# Converting a string to integer in C for arduino

Tags: c, string, arduino, numbers, atoi

I'm trying to use the ATOI library function in C for Arduino to convert a string to an unsigned int.  Out of all number data types I have chosen unsigned int as the number range does not need to be negative, and does not need a large positive number range. The highest would be 300000.

After researching I have found that the maximum number ATOI can spit out is 32767 before it then starts producing garbage (according to this forum post https://forum.arduino.cc/t/maximum-atoi-string/87722 ).

I have had a look around at some other library functions to handle a number of this size, but they seem to support other number data types (such as long, signed ect) but i'm a little oferwhelmed with one that would suit best, and just wanted to check here first to see if anyone else knew of a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use the `strtol` function which returns a `long`.

Comment: "The highest would be 300000" Tough luck since `unsigned int` can't hold anything larger than 65535 on your system... Numerical limits of integers is one of the first thing one studies when picking up a C book.

Comment: Ahh ok, I was just going off of online articles such as this one https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=types-signed-unsigned-integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `atoi` (family of functions) should never be used for any purpose, since they don't have proper error handling.

The `strtol` (family of functions) should be used instead. It is equivalent except it has error handling and supports other bases than decimal as an option.

Furthermore, you seem unaware that AVR is using 16 bit integers, so an `unsigned int` will only have the range 0 - 65535. If you need numbers up to 300000, you must use `unsigned long`.

Therefore the function you are looking for is `strtoul` from `stdlib.h`. Usage:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned long x = strtoul(str, NULL, 10);
```

---

Please note that using the default "primitive data types" of C in embedded programming is naive. As you've noticed, they are nothing but trouble since their sizes aren't portable. Professional programmers always use `stdint.h` types and never anything else. In this case `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing your own, something like this

```c
const unsigned long fast_atoi_map [] = {
  0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90,
  0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
  0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000,
  0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000,
  0, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000,
};

unsigned long fast_atoi(char *str, unsigned char length) {
  unsigned long val = 0;
  const unsigned long *imap = fast_atoi_map + (length - 2) * 10;
  while (length-- > 1) {
    val = val + *(imap + (*str++ - '0'));
    imap -= 10;
  }
  return val + (*str - '0');
}
```

Comment: Looks like `fast_atoi("0", strlen("0"))` is _undefined behavior_ with `fast_atoi_map + (1 - 2) * 10;`,

Comment: Fast?  `fast_atoi()` omits the cost of finding `length`.  To well compare speeds with `atoi()`, start with a _pointer_ to a _string, not a pointer and `length`.

Comment: > Looks like fast_atoi("0", strlen("0")) is undefined behavior
Have you tried it? 
Thats not true! Because c lets you do stupid things it works just fine. See it here:

https://onlinegdb.com/HqdkrLSa6v

> Fast? Yes.
Traditionally the conversion is done by dividing.
But many mcu don't have the `DIV` instruction and the divide instruction from C translates to a loop of subtraction in machine code.

Comment: `fast_atoi()` still has undefined behavior even if it runs as desired on your [select compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/HqdkrLSa6v).  `fast_atoi_map + (length - 2) * 10` needs repair.

Comment: "Traditionally the conversion is done by dividing." is amiss.  Typical `atoi()` code rarely use `DIV`.  A simple alternative is `unsigned long faster_atoi(char *str) { unsigned long val = 0; while (*str) { val = val * 10 + (*str++ - '0'); } return val }`.  No UB, no look-up table, no divide.  Even the `val * 10` can be easily be replaced by a good compiler without `*` instructions.

Comment: Arduino mcu like the atmega328 doesn't have `DIV` or `MUL` instructions. Multiplication is just as bad. Try to compile the code with avr-gcc and then inspect the assembly (you can use avr-objdump) and you'll understand what I am talking about.

Comment: kcsoft, "Multiplication is just as bad" (as `DIV`) is hardly true.  `DIV` is often much slower than `MUL`.  Even `mul` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75809270/converting-a-string-to-integer-in-c-for-arduino/75809452?noredirect=1#comment133735040_75809452) code, the only multiply needed is `* 10`, easily replaceable by a `((val << 2) + val) << 1`.  A good compiler, with optimizations enabled, will emit 3 shifts and add even if one codes `val * 10`.